# MPMoviePlayerController don't want to work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm using cocos2d and i want to play a movie.

I've created a `CCLayer` subclass and reimplemented it's `init` method like this:

```
-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"common/test-movie.mp4"];
        MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:[player view]];
        [player play];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I've run `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:scene];` with the scene contains only this layer. But nothing is displayed :( Just a black screen.

**EDIT**

Also it always returns 0 duration for every movie. I've even tried to play a video from iPhone's camera - the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in NSURL - i was created it in not right way. Here is the right code:

```
NSString *rootPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString *filePath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test-movie.mp4"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting the view frame?

```
id parentView = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView];
[parentView addSubview:[player view]];
[[player view] setFrame:[parentView bounds]];
```